# Driving a piezo speaker at 40 KHz

Tags: mosfet-driver, speakers, ultrasound, piezo

I'm trying to drive [this](http://www.bestgrouptechnologies.com/doc/KSN-1076A-Datasheet.pdf) piezo element at 40 kHz but am running into troubles when using a function generator since the element requires greater drive.

I got the guts of an ultrasonic cleaner to drive the element, but it was modulating at about 10 kHz.

Could anyone give advice on how to drive the element?

I also can't derive what voltage it wants to be driven at, either.

Comment: It is an 8 Ohm speaker  rated for 50W.  So, around 20V RMS maximum.

Comment: It will draw 2.5A at 20Vrms (56Vpp). I don't know if that is what you want. Either way, you need an audio power amplifier to drive it. Use the function generator to provide signal into the audio amplifier. I hope the function generator was protected against output shorts and is still working, they are usually rated for 50 ohm output impedance.

Comment: Thank you @Indraneel and JRE. I just drove it with a function generator through an L293D H bridge at 24Vpp, it was drawing 1.2A, and somehow the 50W rated speaker died. The function generator is still fine. At this point i'm going to look for another tweeter as I can't put my finger on why it burnt out. 

Do you have a suggestion for the audio power amplifier?

Comment: *I just drove it with a function generator through an L293D H bridge at 24Vpp* Then you drove it with a **square wave** (not a sine-wave). Square waves have the property that they contain lots of **harmonic frequencies** which can destroy a tweeter, as you discovered. Also, the power rating might not be exactly what is listed in the specs. The rating might be a **peak rating** meaning, it can handle that power **for a very short time only**. Any way, don't use the L293 for audio, it is designed to drive a motor. Same as you should not use an audio amplifier to power a motor.

Comment: I suggest that you educate yourself on speakers, audio signals etc, basically all that is involved because if you don't and do more or less the same to a different tweeter, **that tweeter will also be destroyed** (I guarantee it). The speakers simply cannot handle the amount of power you feed them.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the function generator was outputting a sine wave.

Comment: @Orbitronics:  The **signal generator** was putting out a sine wave.  The 293 was making nice, sharp, vicious square waves out of your sine wave.

Comment: Also, 50W is the **maximum.**  You want to stay well under that.

Comment: *the function generator was outputting a sine wave* Yes but the L293 is a **switching** device, its switches are either on or off. That means the output connects to ground or it connects to the supply. It cannot output voltages "in the middle". So it cannot output a sinewave. Instead it outputs a square wave of some sorts. And that **destroys** almost any tweeter instantly.

Comment: Any audio amplifier should do. Even TDA2030 is fine upto 50K Hz.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie why would square wave be a problem? Isn't it just a bunch of sine waves? Anyway, first figure of the datasheet says 2.83Vrms. This translates to 353.75 mA, somewhat more than the typical ability of a 200mA function generator, but way less than the 1.2A the OP put it through. I'm inclined to think that 2.5A is indeed the peak rating for maybe milli seconds or less. 2.83V comes to about 1W continuous, so 50W is definitely 5 times more than what is usual for "peak".

Comment: I wonder what will happen if OP complains to manufacturer since it was running at 11.52 W.... although datasheet does not give specifications for continuous use, but does limit temperature to 99C.

Comment: @JRE I had been under the impression the tweeter could handle the square wave because that's how i drive this transducer https://www.murata.com/products/productdetail?partno=MA40S4S I have learnt the hard way that tweeters are indeed very different.